# Google Chrome on Ubuntu 12.04 Freezes My Laptop

Tags: google-chrome, shutdown

When I install google chrome on my ubuntu 12.04 and start working in chrome, my computer  freezes. I can't move my mouse or do anything, so I must force shut down and hold the power button on my laptop.

Any help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Chrome causing freeze is a known issue, but mostly related to newer hardware and the Linux kernel.
If your computer has new hardware, it possible that the Linux kernel in 12.04 (3.2) is a bit behind and has some compatibility issues with the hardware. This is known to cause occasional computer freezes and alike. You can easily upgrade to the newer kernel (3.5) that is included with newer Ubuntu releases, and if that is not the problem you can easily go back. Here it how you do it:

1) In terminal window type:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-quantal
```

2) if asked whether to install all necessary packages enter Y

3) reboot to use the newest kernel

4) you can still boot with the old kernel through your GRUB boot menu (to get to it, hold Shift during boot)

Hope that helps!

Comment: I've searched for hours about this answer, and this is the best and simple ! Thanks a lot !